# Android WebView JavaScript Enabled

Tags: xss, android, javascript, mobile

I recently found an Android application, which uses a WebView with enabled JavaScript. In this webview I am able to browse from their provided FAQ page to twitter, and from twitter basically everywhere I want.

So my question is: Is this a vulnerability I need to report? Is XSS in updated WebViews still a thing, since I am able to escape the website of the app and browse anywhere I want?

I tried to find answers in Google, but did not manage to find any updated information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is being able to browse to any page inside this app's webview a functionality that this app provides? If so, then it is not a vulnerability. I recently posted a very descriptive blog explaining about webviews, while giving references to many other good blogs around it too. You may check want to check it out : http://www.nuckingfoob.me/android-webview-csp-iframe-sandbox-bypass/index.html